# Transpose : Matrices and Orders of

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is my Answers and Reasoning, all I ask is that you check it and direct me if I have gone wrong, Thank you!

[image]

Number 2 - because (BC)^T equals C^T x B^T which is a 5x2 matrix. This multiplied by A will become a 3x2 matrix.

[image]

Number 1 - because same reasoning as above.. C^T is a 5x5 matrix and B^T is a sx5 matrix In order for them to be able to be multiplied together C^T's columns must equal B^T's rows. therefore s = 5

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct. There is really only one rule you need to get them:

> If $A$ is a $m_1\times n_1$ matrix and $B$ is a $m_2\times n_2$ matrix, then $AB$ is defined if and only if $n_1=m_2$. If this is the case, then $AB$ is a $m_1\times n_2$ matrix.